# How to auto play ppt in fulll screen. inside iframe with changing slides with configurable duration?

Tags: html, web, iframe, office365, powerpoint

I am rendering a ppt inside an iframe with the help of https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx
and it is working as expected. but want to jump into the full screen preview with changing slides automatically

````
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[https://www.your_website/file_name.pptx]' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0'>```
````